# VB.NET form not already selected when opened

Tags: vb.net, forms, select, focus, infinite-loop

I open a custom form from another with ShowDialog(),

The problem is that this freshly opened form is not already selected, but just on top. This causes that **I can't capture key presses or have my first tab index already selected until I click once on the form**.

Anyone can help me ?

I already tried these in the Form_Load and it doesn't work yet :

```
Me.Activate()
Me.BringToFront()
Me.Focus()
Me.Show()
Me.Select()
```

I did not found an answer yet from searching on Google.

Comment: whene you use Showdialog() the form will be shown on TopMost so the other form will be sent to the front you cant focus on it till the showdialog will be closed

Comment: t sounds you have a timer or a handler that handels and focus on the above form so you lost the focus on the dialogued form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds you have a `timer` or a `handler` that `handles` and `focus` on the above form so you loose the focus on the freshly dialogued form.

Solution:
- Remove the loop or handler that focus on your form and do it on a background or something more external or after the Form_Load.

*To be clear: when you use ShowDialog() the form will be shown on TopMost so the other form will be sent to the front you cant focus on it till the Dialog will be closed

Comment: YOU FOUND IT! It works without my "loop"... On the load I instantiate a class which starts an "endless" loop. But this loop should still less the application "breath" because I put `Application.DoEvents()`... Also this loops call a sub from the form each 30 of a second. How could I avoid this loop from making weird things such as this?

Comment: It works with the "ShowDialog" and without the loop, but I need it

Comment: Can I use a thread instead? I fear background workers as hell.

Comment: backgroundworker do work without focusing on the form try and let me know it is kind of thread

Comment: @Che let me know the results ?

Comment: (I was writing) It may sound controversial, but it worked with a timer at the start xD. It only delays of 1 ms the entrance in the endless loop, and then the timer stop at this first tick. MAGIC isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this if you don't have a very slow computer :

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   ClickForm.Interval(1000)
   ClickForm.Start()

   'Set the interval and start the timer

End Sub

Private Sub ClickForm_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ClickPanel.Tick
   'Wait for form charging

    Me.Select()

   'Select the form

End Sub
```

Obviously you need to add a timer to your project...